# How to open image in my ios app from another app?

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, instagram

As Instagram and some another apps have option to open image in there app from any other app. I also want to do similar kind of thing for my iOS image processing app. So user can open there image from any app in my iPhone/iPad app. But I don't know how it is possible.

Answer (score 9):

Navigate to your project.

Select your app target and open "info" tab.

Now in "Document Types" add a document type with these settings:

```
Name: "whatever" or "image"

Types: public.image
```

Save this and compile the app. Now your app should show in open in... list from other apps.

Now follow apple [Opening Supported File Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html) and continue your development

For a complete list of types follow this: [Uniform Type Identifiers Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i already did this before 2 years :)

Comment: anyway, other people might find it interesting!

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can open any file type in other supported application in your iOS device with "Open In" option.

Please follow this apple document for **[Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1)** will be helpful to you.

1) You can also refer this **[tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios)**  In which explain with example of pdf file.

2) For customisation check [**this**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH201-SW1) and other possible types found **[here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1)**
you can manage different types of document by adding UTI.

Comment: yes for that refere tutorial in that they explain about UTI by apple i also add new link for UTI by apple please check that.

Comment: what type of LSItemContentTypes set for import purpose ? if it`s not working with default import UTI for image. then you can try it by create/register your own format for .png and .jpeg. same as given apple link topic name "Registering the File Types Your App Supports". Also in tutorial you find topic with name "Importing Self-Defined Documents"

Comment: @Deniz yes i also found after iOS 6.0 this issue occurs. But for common UTI and open IN feature this one is useful.