# ios launch my app from the photos application with a selected image

Tags: ios

I want the ability to have a user select an image in the PHOTO app and launch my app. M app would then read that image and future process it. The user would continue to remain in my app.

I have been reading on "Share Extensions" but they do not appear to be what i need. They appear to be for when the user wants to QUICKLY share info. They are not for when the user wants to send info to another app.

I have been able to do this easily in android but any starting points on what i need to do?

Comment: Potentially the first extension type on the developer docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/

Comment: @evan I don't think that is what I need. I want the user to basically move from the photos app to my app with the details of the photo.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106461/how-to-open-image-in-my-ios-app-from-another-app